# ionic 3 angular messed up page layout

Tags: angular, ionic3

i have done many pages in ionic 3. but this particular is messed up for beyond my understanding. There is no css applied. just all plain ionic component. 
it looks like:

```
<ion-content>
<form [formGroup]="settings" (ngSubmit)="saveSettings()">
   <ion-list no-lines padding>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="chatHost" placeholder="chat server url"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>  
      <ion-item >
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="channelId" [disabled]="useGse == true" placeholder="channel id"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

      <button ion-button type="submit" class="settings-button" [disabled]="settings.controls['chatHost'].value === ''" full>Save</button>
   </ion-list>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

and appearance is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wusu10ngxukt13n/Screenshot%202017-07-28%2019.47.36.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Put the repeated `br`'s the the button outside of the `ion-list`. This is likely having an impact. As a side note, I would suggest using css to create the spacing above the button instead of the `br`'s.

Comment: removed no luck though

Comment: What does it look like with the button moved?